# DataNitro - copying from the shell into an editor

Tags: python, pandas, datanitro

I'm using DataNitro and would like to be able to copy output from the Excel Shell and paste into my editor. However, I can't find a way to do that. Any idea how I might do that?

Answer (score 0):

Right click in the shell, click "mark", highlight the region you want to copy, and press enter. It'll then be in your clipboard and you can paste it into an editor.

(This is the way to copy things from a windows command prompt in general, which is where the shell is running.)

Comment: Brilliant - thanks for this! I love your software by the way - it's a dream come true.